# EXT js How to invoke Store synchronously

Tags: javascript, synchronization, extjs5, extjs6

I need to figure out how to call this function synchronously.

```
    fetchData: function(recs){
    store = Ext.getStore('OutOfBalanceList');
    store.reload({
        params: {
            startDate: searchForm.startDate,
            endDate: searchForm.endDate,
            cusip: searchForm.cusip,
            account: searchForm.account
        },
        callback: function (records, options, success) {
            recs = records.length;
            return recs;
        }
    });
},
```

I appreciate all the sermons about Async, but in this case I have to use Synchronous calls because when the data returned is empty, I have to call back again with different parameters.  Presently this ends up being an infinite loop because "recs" is not changed outside!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try and make it synchronous. Do the "call again with different parameters" inside your callback method. Something like this:

```
fetchData: function(recs) {
  var me = this;
  store = Ext.getStore('OutOfBalanceList');
  store.reload({
    params: {
      startDate: searchForm.startDate,
      endDate: searchForm.endDate,
      cusip: searchForm.cusip,
      account: searchForm.account
    },
    callback: function (records, options, success) {
      if (records.length == 0) {
        me.fetchDataWithDifferentParameters();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

If you're going to work with JavaScript frameworks and calls to external data sources, then learning how to use callbacks is pretty darn important.

Comment: I did figure this out, but grateful for your answer.  It seems the EXTJS does not support Synchronous calls.  The me = this;  tripped me up for a while.  So, I accept your answer.  By the way, are you My old friend Bob Watkins from Queens?

Comment: You can make it do synchronous calls - the proxy can be configured to use synchronous AJAX support (though that's discouraged, and browser support for it has been deprecated). But it's a bad idea - the entire browser is locked up during the call. Never been to Queens; I live in Australia.